# Using Fiddler2 to txt log webpage traffic in real-time?

Tags: vb.net, logging, httpwebrequest, html, fiddler

Me and a few other people are developing a piece of software that measures levels of distraction based on some user settings.

The user will be able to designate certain programs, websites, etc. as "on task" and anything else will be considered "off task" by the program.

The only road block we have run into is being able to grab the user's current web page in real time -- at any given second we need to be able to programatically determine what web page the user is viewing (in any browser) and determine whether it falls under "on task" or "off task".

We would like to do this by creating a C# extension for Fiddler2 but are open to other suggestions as well (the software itself is programmed in VB.NET). Anyone have any advice on this? We have been struggling with it for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler catches requests from the browser, instead of reporting on what the browser is doing, so I don't think that you'll have much success using it for this purpose.  If a visitor has a page which makes no requests open their browser, Fiddler won't see anything.  Similarly, Fiddler won't see new requests when a user switches tabs.

You might have better success by looking into browser add-ons / extensions.